# Como cancelar o enter do EditText?

Tags: java, android

Eu gostaria que no teclado não acontecesse de quando o usuário tocasse no enter não fosse para o próximo EditText.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Tenta mudar o 'android:singleLine=true' do XML ou adicionar o mesmo

Comment: Oi de novo Matheus

Comment: Não resolveu não...

Comment: Teria como você colocar seu xml na pergunta?

Comment: Você precisa que faça alguma ação específica ou que ele pule uma linha? E se possível colocar o XML de EditText para que possamos dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 4):

Esse código deve resolver o seu problema: `myEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE);`

Comment: vou testar amigo valeu

Comment: disponha, se resolver marque a resposta como solução do problema pra ajudar quem buscar o mesmo questionamento.

Comment: Ainda não tive tempo de fazer isso...só um instante